# app engine user details into template

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am currently coding in google appengine and python. I am working on the user side of things. At the moment I am passing through if the user is authenticated, login or logout urls for the user as well as some URLs that are unique.
I seem to be repeating code for every new request handler I create. Can you please give me suggestions on how to do this more efficiently. 
Thank you for your help.

Karim

Comment: Yes, you have to extract lines 24-36, put that in a seperate module and then you can.. just kidding. I have no idea. Impossible to tell without seeing your code

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you repeat code in your handlers, create a BaseHandler.

Example BaseHandler using webapp2 and jinja. More [here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-dispatch) about overriding dispatch

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def dispatch(self):
        """ override webapp2 dispatch """

       if user_ok():
           super(BaseHandler, self).dispatch()
       else:
           self.abort(401) 

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(self, template, **template_args):
        self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(template, **template_args))


class YourHandler1(BaseHandler):

    @login_required
    def get(self):

        ....
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This certainly has pointed me in the right direction.